# Drawing full screen post process inner glow in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am looking for a way to create glowing effect along the screen quad edge(inner glow) in GLSL. I know how to create rectangle procedural in fragment shader and how to blur it out so it glows outwards.But I can't figure out how I set just a glow along the screen quad which faces inwards with configurable glow distance and blur level.Any links to relevant examples or documents?
Here is what I need:
[image]

Da code:

```
const vec2 resolution = vec2(800,600);
float rect( vec2 p, vec2 b, float smooth )
{
vec2 v = abs(p) - b;
float d = length(max(v,0.0));
return 1.0-pow(d, smooth);
}

void main( void ) {

vec2 unipos = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution);
vec2 pos = unipos*2.0-1.0;
pos.x *= resolution.x / resolution.y;


float d1 = rect(pos - vec2(-1.0,0.0), vec2(1,1), 0.1); 
vec3 clr1 = vec3(0.2,0.6,1.0) *d1; 



gl_FragColor = vec4( clr1 , 1.0 );

}
```

This code creates full screen rectangle with the outer glow while I need only the glow and it should be inner.

Comment: Crappy version of this I slapped together: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#5888.0

Comment: Thanks ! That is what I need.Do you have an idea how I can smooth the corners a bit ?Well ,I will add a blur to it.